# gunicorn 20.0.4 ignoring --threads argument

Tags: kubernetes, gunicorn

I'm running django in EKS (kubernetes). I have a run script that executes

```
exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi --timeout 30 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /app --workers 1 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --threads 2
```

but when I check the container logs, it seems to be ignoring the fact that I told it to run more than a single thread

```
| [2020-03-12 03:32:33 +0000] [28] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
│ [2020-03-12 03:32:33 +0000] [28] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (28)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
│ [2020-03-12 03:32:33 +0000] [28] [INFO] Using worker: sync                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
│ [2020-03-12 03:32:33 +0000] [30] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30
```

Has anyone else experienced this, or can see something that I'm just not seeing in my config?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a worker class so it probably tried to switch to gthread for you but you likely don't have the futures library loadable? Reagrdless, I really don't recommend gunicorn in k8s. Twisted Web on a thread pool is a much better bet.

Comment: I didn't think I needed futures if I'm running on python 3.6.

Comment: Try passing an explicit worker class of `gthread` and see if you get an error?

Comment: yeah I did that originally, and it seemed to just ignore it. I'm stumped now

Comment: Happy to try twisted - but there is zero info on the googles about setting it up with django

Comment: https://gist.github.com/coderanger/c67d3df255bcbeaf625b6ce038fa2f38 is what I use :) Includes support for Prometheus which you could remove if you don't need it (but prom is cool so maybe try it out)

Comment: Thanks mate. Although it's not directly answering the problem - it has helped me solved the problem.